# pagination $_GET['page'] in php

Tags: php

I have a pagination question. When I load this page in the browser and click on the category link to show my products the first page shows with the products limited and the links for pagination are in place but it keeps sending me to the first page which is zero for whatever pagination link I click on. But the odd thing is is when I change

```
$offset=($pageNum - 1) * $perPage;
```

to

```
$offset=($pageNum)= $perPage;
```

if shows the rest of the products I'm trying to show after clicking on the category. So the problem might be in the page or somewhere around there.

Here is my code.

```
<?php
$productUlList="";
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
include_once "convenientglobal2localhost.php";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category WHERE 1")or die(mysql_error());


while($rowp=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $categoryId=$rowp['catId'];
    $categoryName=$rowp['catName'];
 $productUlList.='
    <ul id="ul" >
        <li id="lists"> <a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?category='.$categoryName.'"> '.$categoryName.'   </a> </li> 
    </ul>';
}
?>
<?php
$msg_to_user3='';

$productList.='';
$categoryList='';
include_once "convenientglobal2localhost.php";
 $perPage= 3;
if(isset($_GET['category']))


$categoryNames=$_GET['category'];
$pageNum=(isset($_GET['page']))? (int)$_GET['page']: 1;
$pages_query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products INNER JOIN category ON categoryName=catName WHERE categoryName='$categoryNames'");
$numrows= mysql_num_rows($pages_query);
 $maxpages=ceil($numrows / $perPage);
 $offset=($pageNum-1) * $perPage;
if ($offset < 0)
 {
 $offset = 0 ;
 }


include_once "convenientglobal2localhost.php";
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE categoryName='$categoryNames' LIMIT $offset, $perPage")or die(mysql_error());
$num=mysql_num_rows($results);

if($num > 0){


while($row=mysql_fetch_array($results)){


 $productId=$row['productId'];
 $productName=$row['name'];
 $productDescription=$row['description'];
 $productPrice=$row['price'];
 $productDiscountedPrice=$row['discountedPrice'];
 $productStock=$row['stock'];
 $productCategory=$row['categoryName'];
 $categoryId=$row['catId'];
 $catName=$row['catName'];

 $categoryList='<table><th id="toptable"></th></table>
 <table id="categorytable">
 <th><img src="inventory_category_images/' . $categoryId . '.jpg" width="498px"; height="125px";/></th> 
</table>';
 $productList.='<table id="productoutputtable">
 <tr>
 <td rowspan="7" valign="top"><img style="border-style=solid; border-color:#767475; padding=; "src="inventory_images/' . $productId . '.jpg" width="150" height="135"/>
    </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr> 
    <td id="tablecolor" ><strong>Product</strong></td> 
    <td colspan="2">' . $productName . ' </td> 
    <td id="tablecolor"><strong>Category</strong></td> 
    <td>' . $productCategory . ' </td> 
    </tr>
     <tr> 
    <td id="tablecolor"><strong>Description:</strong></td> 
     <td colspan="3">' . $productDescription . ' </td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
    <td id="tablecolor" ><strong>Price:</strong></td> 
     <td>$' . $productPrice . ' </td>
     </tr><tr>
     <td id="tablecolor"colspan="1"><strong>Sale Price:</strong></td> 
    <td>$' . $productDiscountedPrice . ' </td> 
    <td id="tablecolor"colspan="2"><strong>In Stock </strong></td> 
    <td>' . $productStock . ' </td> 
    </tr>
    </table>';

}   

$self= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
 for($page=1; $page<=$maxpages; $page++){
    if($page == $pageNum){
        $nav= "$page";
    }
    else{
        $nav= "<a href=\"$self?page=$page\">$page</a>";
    }
 }

 if($page > 1)
 {
    $page=$pageNum-1;
    $prev ="<a href=\"$self?page=$page\">[Prev]</a>";
    $first="<a href=\"$self?page=1\">[First Page]</a>";
 }
 else
 {
    $prev= "&nbsp";
    $first="&nbsp";
 }
 if($pageNum < $maxPages)
 {
    $page=$pageNum+1;
    $next ="<a href=\"$self?page=$page\">[Next]</a>";
    $last="<a href=\"$self?page=$maxPages\">[Last Page]</a>";
 }
 else
 {
    $next= "&nbsp";
    $last="&nbsp";
 }
$pageList.= $first. $prev. $nav. $next. $last;

 } 
else{
    $msg_to_user3="You have no products listed.";

}
//$pageList.=""; 
//for($i = 0 ; $i <= $maxpages ; $i++) { 
//if($i == $page) { 
//$pageList.= "<B>$i</B>"; 
//}else{ 
//$pageList.= '<A HREF="?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</A>';
//
//} 
//}
?>
```

Thanks for all you help!!!

Comment: What exactly is the question? It's difficult to trace such lengthy code.

Comment: Don't do a `select *` then use mysql_num_rows(). You're forcing the DB to waste a LOT of effort fetching data from disk that you're just throwing away. use a `select count(*)` and fetch the ONE row result from that instead.

Comment: FYI, you are **wide open** to SQL injection and you **will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Learn to use prepared queries with PDO to avoid this problem entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I'll ignore the inefficiencies (refer to comments on your question). The problem is not your offsetting code—that works fine. Your links are broken.

When generating your numbered links into `$nav`, you need to append, not overwrite. Use `.=`, not `=`. Also, beware of capitalization. `$maxpages` is not `$maxPages`.

Here's updated code. [Proof this works](http://designbynikhil.com/pagination.php). Unless your database query is misconstructed (I can't test that, sorry!), you should be good to go.

```
$self= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
 for($page=1; $page<=$maxpages; $page++){
    if($page == $pageNum){
        $nav.= "$page";
    }
    else{
        $nav.= "<a href=\"$self?page=$page\">$page</a>";
    }
 }

 if($page > 1)
 {
    $page=$pageNum-1;
    $prev ="<a href=\"$self?page=$page\">[Prev]</a>";
    $first="<a href=\"$self?page=1\">[First Page]</a>";
 }
 else
 {
    $prev= "&nbsp";
    $first="&nbsp";
 }
 if($pageNum < $maxpages)
 {
    $page=$pageNum+1;
    $next ="<a href=\"$self?page=$page\">[Next]</a>";
    $last="<a href=\"$self?page=$maxpages\">[Last Page]</a>";
 }
 else
 {
    $next= "&nbsp";
    $last="&nbsp";
 }
$pageList.= $first. $prev. $nav. $next. $last;
```

Comment: Well that worked as far as showing all the pagination links but I still can't get to the second page of the products showing. It says I have no products listed which is my SQL num_rows statement. I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Run `SELECT * FROM products WHERE categoryName='$categoryNames' LIMIT 3, 3` on the database manually and see what you get. Your logic seems valid, so the query must be returning zero results. Are you sure you're typing in a valid category? Is the table actually named products?

Comment: Where "manually" means through PHPMyAdmin or another database management program, if possible.

Comment: I foiund a SELECT query that shows all of the listed products manually but the pagination still isn't showing the second page. So for now I'll just Inherit the height of the wrapper and show all of the products in that category. Thanks for you help though.